# my third section does not get height when using the grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create landing page in css grid & flexbox

All other sections get height but the third one doesn't get height

setting its height manually worked but I want all sections to get the height using grid properties

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  height: 10000px;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto max-content;
  grid-template-columns: 4fr;
}

.grid-wrapper>* {
  clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 0 100%);
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

.grid-wrapper>*:first-child {
  height: 200px;
  clip-path: none;
}

.grid-wrapper>*:nth-child(1),
.grid-wrapper>*:nth-child(3),
.grid-wrapper>*:nth-child(5),
.grid-wrapper>*:nth-child(7),
.grid-wrapper>*:nth-child(9) {
  background: #f2f4f9;
}

.grid-wrapper nav {
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.grid-wrapper header {
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.grid-wrapper section:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.grid-wrapper section:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-row: 4/5;
}

.grid-wrapper section:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-row: 5/6;
}

.grid-wrapper section:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-row: 6/7;
}

.grid-wrapper main {
  grid-row: 7/8;
}

.grid-wrapper section:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-row: 8/9;
}

.grid-wrapper footer {
  grid-row: 9/10;
}

.grid-wrapper section:nth-of-type(6) {
  grid-row: 10/11;
}
```

```html
  <!-- Ineserting Montserrat Google Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <nav></nav>
    <header></header>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <main></main>
    <section></section>
    <footer></footer>
    <section></section>
  </div>
```

I didn't add a text content yet, I want first to make the diagonal sections responsive then start the next part

Comment: we need your html code

Comment: @TemaniAfif I updated it

Comment: Where's the flexbox part of the attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are overcomplicating the code when you can write an easier one like below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 200px;  /* the height of the first row */
  grid-auto-rows: 100vh; /* the height of all the other rows */
}

.grid-wrapper>* {
  clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 0 100%);
  background:yellow;
}

.grid-wrapper>*:first-child {
  clip-path: none;
}

.grid-wrapper>*:nth-child(1),
.grid-wrapper>*:nth-child(3),
.grid-wrapper>*:nth-child(5),
.grid-wrapper>*:nth-child(7),
.grid-wrapper>*:nth-child(9) {
  background: #f2f4f9;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <nav></nav>
  <header></header>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <main></main>
  <section></section>
  <footer></footer>
  <section></section>
</div>
```

And in case you want a continuous shape, simply add a negative margin:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 200px;  /* the height of the first row */
  grid-auto-rows: 100vh; /* the height of all the other rows */
}

.grid-wrapper>* {
  margin:-20vh 0; /* added */
  clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 0 100%);
  background:yellow;
}

.grid-wrapper>*:first-child {
  clip-path: none;
}

.grid-wrapper>*:nth-child(1),
.grid-wrapper>*:nth-child(3),
.grid-wrapper>*:nth-child(5),
.grid-wrapper>*:nth-child(7),
.grid-wrapper>*:nth-child(9) {
  background: #f2f4f9;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <nav></nav>
  <header></header>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <main></main>
  <section></section>
  <footer></footer>
  <section></section>
</div>
```